# Crontab stopped unexpectedly

Tags: cron

I have following entries in the crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131111011431/script/rubber cron --task util:rotate_logs --directory=/mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131111011431/log

0 4 * * * /mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131111011431/voylla_scripts/cj_daily.sh

0 2 * * 6 /mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131111011431/voylla_scripts/cj_saturday.sh
```

I worked fine until today. It didn't run as scheduled after a capistrano deploy, didn't get a mail either. It worked fine earlier, and I am unable to understand what wrong. The only change that was made was the deploy, but I think it should not affect the cron.

I tried using `pgrep cron` to see if crons is working. It gives 904 as output.

Could someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you try bouncing the crond?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Do you mean stop and start again?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Restart crontab : /etc/init.d/crond restart

check your crontab works correctly by simple example.